# Iterate over all rows of a table in jQuery knowing the table element

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am getting a table element for a given row in the table using the following code in jQuery 1.8.2.

```
var tbl = $("input[id$='chkSelectAll']").closest('table');
```

Now, I want to replace the JavaScript code below with corresponding jQuery script. 
**What would be the jQuery for this code below?**

It would be nice if I could just get the table rows as an array from the above tbl variable in jQuery, as that would solve my problem.

```
    for (var i = 1;i < tbl.rows.length - 1;i++) {
         var chk = tbl.rows[i].cells[0].firstChild; //we have a checkbox in first cell of every row
        chk.checked = chkAll.checked; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var rows = $('tr', tbl);
 for (var i = 1;i < rows.size() - 1; i++) {
     rows.eq(i).find('td:first').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true );
    }
```

You can use "chkAll.prop('checked')" instead of "true" assuming that you have chkAll as jQuery object of that checkbox

Comment: Michael - Thanks. What is eq(i)? Probably, the element at i.

Comment: Michael - There is one problem wit your code.  In FF and IE 10. I get as undefined for this expression: $("input[id$='chkSelectAll']").closest('table').find('tr').eq(1).find('td:first').find('checkbox').attr('id')

Comment: Try to break it down into many lines so you can know which one is not working.. Or if you could post a new question with jsFiddle would be better

Comment: I think the problem in expression is .find('checkbox'). May be it should be .find('input') as there is no element of checkbox type. A checkbox is of input type. Right?

Comment: This is what works: $("input[id$='chkSelectAll']").closest('table').find('tr').eq(i).find('td:first').find('input').prop('checked') OR $("input[id$='chkSelectAll']").closest('table').find('tr').eq(i).find('td:first').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked')

Comment: So I think the problem is .find('checkbox') should be either .find('input:checkbox') Or .find('input') since there is only one input element in first cell of the row.